# How to stop weblogic access logs encoding the request url

Tags: weblogic12c, request-uri

In the weblogic access logs, request url is getting printed in encoded format. Like "&" character is actually getting printed as "&"
How to fix this ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: I do not think it is possible to change how WebLogic writes this information but you can create your own custom field in the access log which will print url in unencoded format. Refer to this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/web_server.htm#CNFGD207) and chapter "Creating Custom Field Identifiers" for details.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the insight. I did customize the access logs before, let me try it in that case.